# get answers for a blog post using csom

Tags: blog, client-object-model, community-site

I am trying to find out how to get answers for a blog post in a community site using javascript or csom. I made a search on the Internet unfortunately didn't find anything.

Comment: Do you mean comments for a blog post instead of answers?

Comment: Yes, I mean comments.

Answer (score 1):

In every blog site there is one Comments list. Always called "Comments". In this list there is a column called Post ID.

Therefore if you already have your post, you grab the ID, look at the comments list and query for all comments where Post ID = Blog Post ID. A simple CSOM CAML query should do it. (Looking at the Post Id column it is stored as 1;#1 so you might have to do some manipulation before performing the query)

This blog should help you write your JavaScript http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/07/19/working-with-the-ecmascript-client-object-model-jsom-in-sharepoint-2010-part-3-nikhil-sachdeva.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find any comments list in my Site Collection which is a Community Site.

Comment: A community site doesn't have blogs on them they have discussions. Blogs are separate type of sites.